# Live Video Stream support for android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, android-video-player, wowza

I have a live video feed in m3u8 format and works great in iphone android doesnt support it.
Im planing to convert the feed using ffmpeg and just wondering what the best format/codec/protocol works best with the lowest version of android possible.

thanks so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Video Streaming - Device supported?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256549/android-video-streaming-device-supported)

Comment: You can use use Wowza 3 to stream on multiple Android devices over rtsp protocol starting from Android OS 2.3. Http protocol is only supported by Android os 3.0+. Here is a complete chart for codecs supported by different OS versions http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html