# Buffering problems with android.media.MediaPlayer

Tags: android, asynchronous, media-player

I'm trying to implement a MediaPlayer on an Android app, but now I have two problems, which are not THE BIG SHOWSTOPPER but they are more then annoying and i have to fix it, just for me.

I implemented a async MediaPlayer+Controller to a Activity, which works fine.
My plan was to show also the percentage of the buffering on the MediaControl. This also works.

But now, after I can see the percentage, I saw a strange behaviour: if I seek to a position which is already in the buffer, the buffering will start from this position again. Is this a known and/or normal behavior/problem/feature ?

Here are more details:

I'm using the 2.2 SDK
This is how I implement it

```
public class Details extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaController.MediaPlayerControl { 

[...]

private void setPosition(int currentPos ){
    position = currentPos;
}

[...]

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

[...] 

mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int progress) {
                setPosition(progress);
            }
        });

[...]

public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return position;
}

[...]

public void seekTo(int i) {
    General.mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
}
}
```

[image]

What I expected after clicking on the seekbar

[image]

What I got

[image]

Is this normal?

Comment: +1 because of image illustration:D

Comment: Hey g.tobi. Any luck with this?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer..I didn't fixed it yet :(

Comment: what does the log say? usually media player is pretty verbose..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212688/mediaplayer-seekto-does-not-work-for-unbuffered-position) confirms that although a position is already buffered MediaPlayer sends a request to a server.