# Mediaplayer should play only last seconds of an Audiofile

Tags: java, android, media-player, seconds, playsound

I wanted to implement an function that plays only the last 5 seconds of an Audiofile (wich is longer than 5 seconds). 
Does Mediaplayer somehow support that?

I know how to normally play an Audio file + I know how to get the duration of the file, but how do I set the Mediaplayer to play only the short part at the end?
So that means playing from a specific timecode in the Audiofile.

Comment: as you know that how to get duration. then working on thread and get the last duration. and play it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to implement this would be to use [`MediaPlayer.getDuration()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getDuration%28%29) method to get the audio file duration and then use the [`MediaPlayer.seetTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo%28int%29) API to move to that position..

In your case you can try `mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getDuration()-(5*1000));`...

Comment: Thank you. Works perfect! Didn't know that it would be that easy.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a call to `seekTo` after preparing.

Take a look at this example :

```
this._mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
this._mediaPlayer.reset();
this._mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
this._mediaPlayer.setDataSource( _data_source_ );
this._mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
this._mediaPlayer.prepare();
this._mediaPlayer.start();
/* Seeking to 1 minute */
this._mediaPlayer.seekTo(60 * 1000);
/* Issue a start in the OnSeekCompleteListener */
```

Adapt this example to get the duration of a stream once it is prepared and seek to the duration - 5 seconds (if the media is at least 5 seconds long, in your case).

**However**, it seems that Android has a bug related to the use of `seekTo` when seeking to an unbuffered par of the media. Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4124) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212688/mediaplayer-seekto-does-not-work-for-unbuffered-position) for more informations. This bug should have been resolved in *Android 2.2*.